# Can not limit commands user can run as root in devtoolset-3 enabled shell

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo

We are using devtoolset-3 on RHEL6.6. Users run scl enable devtoolset-3 bash in order to access an environment with all the devtoolset-3 tools.

I would like to allow users to run a subset of commands as root. The normal way to do this is to use sudo with a sudoers file containing a command alias with a list of commands you want the user to be able to execute as root.

I have tried various combinations but I can't come up with the right recipe.

Below are some of the things I have tried:

Attempt 1:

I create a command alias:

```
Cmnd_Alias ALLOWEDCOMMANDS=/usr/bin/pkill <process name>
```

and then allow members of myGroup to execute those commands without a password

```
%myGroup  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:SETENT: ALLOWEDCOMMANDS
```

With that setup if I try and run sudo pkill  I get:

> Sorry, user  is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/scl enable
>   devtoolset-3  'pkill' ''' as root

Attempt 2:

I modified the sudoers file to have the complete command:

```
Cmnd_Alias ALLOWEDCOMMANDS=/usr/bin/scl enable devtoolset-3 pkill <some_process_name>
```

but I still get the same error.

Attempt 3:

If I list `/usr/bin/scl` as an allowed command then the user is allowed to execute any command as root in an scl enabled environment.

Can anyone come up with a reliable way to allow users to run a certain list of commands in a scl enabled shell?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else runs into this problem I thought I'd post the answer that I received from red hat support here.

it turns out that the devtoolset-3 version of sudo doesnt play nicely the format of command alias's you can specify in /etc/sudoers.

In your devtoolset-3 enabled shell you can alias sudo=/usr/bin/sudo. Then your users will run the standard sudo which does handle command aliases correctly.

With that alias in place everything works as expected.